# jump to a specific image in a gallery by clicking on an interactive image map - wordpress

Tags: wordpress, gallery, imagemap, run-script

I am trying to create on my WordPress website something similar to this:
[Link](https://kastell.qodeinteractive.com/property-item/modern-villa/#:%7E:text=OUR%20GALLERY-,Layouts%20Plan,-PHOTOS), where you have an image map on the right and by clicking on a certain section of the image, the gallery on the left will jump to a specific image.
The interactive image map I'm using is called Image map pro and you can play around with it on their website https://imagemappro.com/editor/index.html.

I think the way I can do this is by making a "run script" action happen when a shape within the image is clicked that corresponds to the specific image I want to jump to in the gallery but I don't know what code to enter to get that done.[where I need to enter the custom code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRtCU.png)
as of now I didn't decide on a gallery plugin yet so any that you can get to work would be fine (preferably free)
Thanks!

Below is code you can import into the image map pro editor to get started

```
{
  "id": 2760,
  "editor": {
    "tool": "select",
    "shapeCounter": {
      "rects": 1,
      "polys": 6
    }
  },
  "general": {
    "name": "test",
    "shortcode": "test1",
    "height": 628,
    "naturalHeight": 628
  },
  "image": {
    "url": "https://user-140471889-work.colibriwp.com/personal-stylist-pro/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/map-floor-plan-img.png"
  },
  "spots": [
    {
      "id": "poly-7168",
      "title": "Poly 0",
      "type": "poly",
      "x": 1.252,
      "y": 13.297,
      "width": 37.375,
      "height": 75.478,
      "x_image_background": 1.252,
      "y_image_background": 13.297,
      "width_image_background": 36.875,
      "height_image_background": 74.68152866242038,
      "actions": {
        "click": "run-script"
      },
      "mouseover_style": {
        "background_color": "#fff24d"
      },
      "tooltip_content": {
        "squares_settings": {
          "containers": [
            {
              "id": "sq-container-403761",
              "settings": {
                "elements": [
                  {
                    "settings": {
                      "name": "Heading",
                      "iconClass": "fa fa-header"
                    },
                    "options": {
                      "heading": {
                        "text": "Poly 0"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "points": [
        {
          "x": 100,
          "y": 0.632912887895431
        },
        {
          "x": 98.99665551839465,
          "y": 89.03013441719526
        },
        {
          "x": 51.17056856187291,
          "y": 89.66273506806598
        },
        {
          "x": 34.448160535117054,
          "y": 99.57868254878576
        },
        {
          "x": 14.381270903010032,
          "y": 100
        },
        {
          "x": 1.0033444816053512,
          "y": 90.50654296904669
        },
        {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 76.58292357146497
        },
        {
          "x": 17.391304347826086,
          "y": 65.40099841586121
        },
        {
          "x": 16.72240802675585,
          "y": 42.4051634889939
        },
        {
          "x": 0.6688963210702341,
          "y": 31.434673432139753
        },
        {
          "x": 0.6688963210702341,
          "y": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "poly-6930",
      "title": "Poly 1",
      "type": "poly",
      "x": 72.252,
      "y": 24.443,
      "width": 26.25,
      "height": 53.026,
      "x_image_background": 72.2515,
      "y_image_background": 24.28407643312102,
      "width_image_background": 25.874999999999996,
      "height_image_background": 52.547770700636946,
      "mouseover_style": {
        "background_color": "#fff24d"
      },
      "tooltip_content": {
        "squares_settings": {
          "containers": [
            {
              "id": "sq-container-403761",
              "settings": {
                "elements": [
                  {
                    "settings": {
                      "name": "Heading",
                      "iconClass": "fa fa-header"
                    },
                    "options": {
                      "heading": {
                        "text": "Poly 1"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "points": [
        {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0
        },
        {
          "x": 100,
          "y": 0.6011525032585591
        },
        {
          "x": 100,
          "y": 100
        },
        {
          "x": 0.4761904761904762,
          "y": 99.70014446831225
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "poly-3017",
      "title": "Poly 2",
      "type": "poly",
      "x": 39.752,
      "y": 13.456,
      "width": 31,
      "height": 67.198,
      "x_image_background": 39.7515,
      "y_image_background": 13.456050955414014,
      "width_image_background": 30.749999999999993,
      "height_image_background": 66.71974522292994,
      "mouseover_style": {
        "background_color": "#fff24d"
      },
      "tooltip_content": {
        "squares_settings": {
          "containers": [
            {
              "id": "sq-container-403761",
              "settings": {
                "elements": [
                  {
                    "settings": {
                      "name": "Heading",
                      "iconClass": "fa fa-header"
                    },
                    "options": {
                      "heading": {
                        "text": "Poly 2"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "points": [
        {
          "x": 37.90322580645162,
          "y": 100
        },
        {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 99.99929858125736
        },
        {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0
        },
        {
          "x": 100,
          "y": 0
        },
        {
          "x": 99.59677419354838,
          "y": 16.58733999832797
        },
        {
          "x": 38.30645161290324,
          "y": 16.823168353957886
        },
        {
          "x": 39.11290322580646,
          "y": 43.83910743137993
        },
        {
          "x": 98.38709677419355,
          "y": 43.60170562289492
        },
        {
          "x": 98.38709677419355,
          "y": 55.68739700281875
        },
        {
          "x": 37.500000000000014,
          "y": 55.68739700281875
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "poly-8378",
      "title": "Poly 3",
      "type": "poly",
      "x": 52.252,
      "y": 25.239,
      "width": 18.375,
      "height": 16.879,
      "x_image_background": 52.1265,
      "y_image_background": 25.239490445859868,
      "width_image_background": 18.249999999999993,
      "height_image_background": 16.401273885350324,
      "mouseover_style": {
        "background_color": "#fff24d"
      },
      "tooltip_content": {
        "squares_settings": {
          "containers": [
            {
              "id": "sq-container-403761",
              "settings": {
                "elements": [
                  {
                    "settings": {
                      "name": "Heading",
                      "iconClass": "fa fa-header"
                    },
                    "options": {
                      "heading": {
                        "text": "Poly 3"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "points": [
        {
          "x": 99.31972789115646,
          "y": 0.9433798507648502
        },
        {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0
        },
        {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 99.99720759564174
        },
        {
          "x": 100,
          "y": 100
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "poly-8159",
      "title": "Poly 4",
      "type": "poly",
      "x": 52.002,
      "y": 51.673,
      "width": 18.75,
      "height": 36.942,
      "x_image_background": 51.8765,
      "y_image_background": 51.672611464968156,
      "width_image_background": 18.374999999999993,
      "height_image_background": 36.146496815286625,
      "mouseover_style": {
        "background_color": "#fff24d"
      },
      "tooltip_content": {
        "squares_settings": {
          "containers": [
            {
              "id": "sq-container-403761",
              "settings": {
                "elements": [
                  {
                    "settings": {
                      "name": "Heading",
                      "iconClass": "fa fa-header"
                    },
                    "options": {
                      "heading": {
                        "text": "Poly 4"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "points": [
        {
          "x": 0.6666666666666669,
          "y": 0
        },
        {
          "x": 99.33333333333333,
          "y": 1.2924717567601982
        },
        {
          "x": 100,
          "y": 100
        },
        {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 99.56960137048941
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "poly-5413",
      "title": "Poly 5",
      "type": "poly",
      "x": 26.627,
      "y": 1.036,
      "width": 25,
      "height": 10.509,
      "x_image_background": 26.7515,
      "y_image_background": 1.035668789808917,
      "width_image_background": 24.5,
      "height_image_background": 9.713375796178344,
      "mouseover_style": {
        "background_color": "#fff24d"
      },
      "tooltip_content": {
        "squares_settings": {
          "containers": [
            {
              "id": "sq-container-403761",
              "settings": {
                "elements": [
                  {
                    "settings": {
                      "name": "Heading",
                      "iconClass": "fa fa-header"
                    },
                    "options": {
                      "heading": {
                        "text": "Poly 5"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "points": [
        {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0.004485025167656873
        },
        {
          "x": 0.5000000000000002,
          "y": 100
        },
        {
          "x": 100,
          "y": 98.48927381987775
        },
        {
          "x": 99.5,
          "y": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```